# It tears me apart, one more time

Tags: riddle, word

```
'1' is not considered as a prime number.
```

Find my true self,
kill eleven Germans
The good disguise wins
so you act as twins

Prime number 7
encrypted in alpha
Now try to soften
but please, not often

Once in front
while twice in rear
The Christians symbol
is what we want here

Two towers of letters,
three floors can be seen
Built close to each other,
what fits in between?

---

What fits in between
has been found before
But one was different,
and is waiting for more

It's not only a symbol
but like a small lagoon
Rising from the dead
every afternoon

Comment: Maybe 31153 ? prime number?

Comment: Can you comment on my answer? Not sure if you saw it.

Comment: Is the answer a word, or could it be a random code?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code a word :)

Comment: TRS sorta looks like "tears" ripped apart, I guess.

Comment: @No.7892142 Well, this riddle is easy.

Comment: It is? I guess the creator would say that!

Comment: @No.7892142 For you it should be very easy :)

Comment: I just noticed this here, which makes me feel more confident about my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

The answer is:

> Tears

From the other hints we get the letters

> TRS

The additional two paragraphs state:
What fits in between
has been found before
But one was different,
and is waiting for more
It's not only a symbol
but like a small lagoon
Rising from the dead
every afternoon

> This is saying that one of the things found is waiting for more. It then says "It's not only a symbol", and the thing found that was a symbol was "The Christians symbol" which was T.

Then the second part of the hint, "but like a small lagoon, Rising from the dead every afternoon"

> The small lagoon could be like a cup of tea. The tea leaves are dried and dead but during the afternoon you have your "afternoon tea" which rises them from the dead.

Also the title is "It tears me apart one more time"

> The letters TRS are torn apart to make tears.

If this is the answer I'd like to give credit to the many people who got hints out of Bobbee and I just pieced them together.

---

EDIT:The answer is

> Reset

So far, the answers from Leslie and Namisca are:

> QRS and STU

Making these as two towers and taking everything in between is:

> R S T

The title of the puzzle is Tear it apart, one more time

> Tear apart RST and make it RESET (RST is a common abbreviation of RESET).

For the added hint, 
"What fits in between
has been found before
But one was different,
and is waiting for more
It's not only a symbol
but like a small lagoon
Rising from the dead
every afternoon"

> Reset is a symbol, "every afternoon" references a daily reset of something like a computer, and the symbol is a circle with a line coming out (rising dead from lagoon), also symbolizing reset).

Comment: I'm not sure which I understand less, the question or this answer...

Comment: You missed more than half of it :)

Comment: Yeah there's just so much going on in the question the only way I could think of it was by isolating one factor (numbers).

Comment: At least you got the "Q" out of prime number 7, very good! :)

Comment: You are way too far :)

Comment: I guess that works. If that's the reasoning, I feel the last two parts are kind of a stretch.

Comment: @No.7892142 they are metaphorically describing a cup of tea which is not very abstract I think. Also note that I created those two verses within 2 minutes to help you guys ;)

Comment: I didn't mean I'd like to give credit literally ;)

Answer (score 7):

Alright, I think I'm getting close. I'm not very confident about my answer to the second half of the first clue, though.

Find my true self,
kill eleven Germans

> I agree with Namisca's reasoning for this as S.

The good disguise wins,
so you act as twins

> This could be saying 'U' (you) act as twins (W). It could also be saying that the clue is the one acting as "twins", so either U or V. I think U works best here, though, with regards to the final solution.

Prime number 7
encrypted in alpha

> As everyone else has already stated, this is Q.

Now try to soften
but please, not often

> "Soften" without "Often" leaves us with S.

Once in front
while twice in rear

> The letter R is in front once, and twice in rear.

The Christians symbol
is what we want here

> The Christian's symbol is usually a cross, which evokes a lowercase T to me.

Two towers of letters,
three floors can be seen
Built close to each other,
what fits in between?

> I think this is trying to make us think about the letters we've just deduced- if my logic is correct, then we're at: 
> S   U 
> Q   S 
> R   T 
>
> The letters that go between these two "towers" are T, R, and S. The 'built close together' clue was what made me think U worked best for the second letter; each "floor" of the towers is only one letter apart.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not quite sure where to go from here. :( That is, of course, unless the answer was supposed to be TURS (Thurs?) in reference to your comment on the original post.. Am I getting warmer?

Comment: I wanted you to look at the "U" again because your explanation was wrong. It has nothing to do with the final solution.

Comment: @bobbee So is TRS the final solution, or is there more?

Comment: @EFrog there is a very little bit more. I just wrote two more verses to make it obvious :) (also there is no correct solution for the letter "U", yet)

Comment: If the twins means double, shouldn't u be w hence ***double*** ***u***

Answer (score 3):

Same as Quark, only an attempt. My current answer:

> SS QO RX ET

I can't make it work with the hint in the title.

Find my true self, kill eleven Germans

> S. Eleven in German is "elf". We delete the "elf" in self.

The good disguise wins so you act as twins

> S. The twins acts as hint to double the previous letter.

Prime number 7 encrypted in alph: As given per Quark's answer.

> Q

Now try to soften but please, not often

> O. We change the letter slighlty we get an O.

Once in the front while twice in the rear

> R.

The Christians symbol is what we want here

> X. ( Xmas.)

Two towers of letters, three floors can be seen

> E. When written in capital the straight lines are the "Floors".

Built close to each other, what fits in between?

> T. It's what is between the letter E in the word letter.

Comment: So you've figured out that you have to look for letters, very good :) Most of them are wrong and I disagree with "E" as "two towers". There is still a long way to go for you my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from everything Leslie has said, the only thing I can think of to add is:

Built close to each other,
what fits in between?

> Out of the TRS Leslie found, the letter T is the only one that fits inside the word "between".

What fits in between
has been found before

> Leslie found T in his/her solution.

But one was different,
and is waiting for more

> Since Leslie's solution was TRS, and the riddle was specifically looking for T, it's different. It's "waiting for more" because it wants to be noticed in the word "between".

It's not only a symbol

> Both "T" and "t" are used as various symbols, marking perpendicular lines and the Christian faith.

but like a small lagoon

> Noooooo clue.

Rising from the dead
every afternoon

> Not sure? Maybe the fact that "T" isn't present in "morning", but reappears each day in the "afTernoon" and stays throughout the "nighT". Ooooor it's referring to "afternoon tea"...

Bobbee's original comment was something like

> "There's going to be golden rain in two days." -- "Golden rain" referring to "ti", a drop of golden sun, and "in two days" being literal -- "in Two days".

Other potential clues that probably aren't clues but are most likely just me being paranoid about everything being a clue... clues.

> The title, twofold. "Tear 'it' apart". If you take it apart, you're left with an I and a T, or literally the phrase, "I, T" a la "I, Robot". Also, "One more time" -- the letter T is often used to denote (or countdown) time. So again, referencing T.

-

> "The good disguise wins, so you act as twins". Aside from somehow (though I'm not 100% sure how) pointing to U, this could also be saying that "wins" is a good disguise for T, like when used in "twins".

-

> "Two towers of letters" could refer to the "two towers" in the middle of the word "leTTers", although I'm not sure, since the "l" also looks like a tower.

- > Actually, that said, "Tear it apart" to get T, then "one more time" to get another T... Along with the repeated "Two Towers" references, the fact that it's "waiting for more..." That could mean that the answer is actually TT? ("TT" does "fit in between" the "leTTers" too) And, incidentally, "TT"could be construed as looking somewhat like a lagoon. *shrug*

Edit #2...

Uh, ok so.

Two towers of letters, what fits in between?

> Letters?

What fits in between has been found before. But one was different and is waiting for more.

> I can't tell you how many letters we've found already. "T" is different in that it occurs twice in the word "letters" (albeit so does E, but it wasn't in the RST tower).

It's not only a symbol but like a small lagoon. Rising from the dead every afternoon.

> This just goes on to further describe which of the letters is "different". So yeah, my final guess is "LETTERS".

If that's not it, then I'll wait for someone else to get it so I can punch myself. :D

Comment: There are clues where you haven't found any :)

Comment: @bobbee Ok check that. Enjoy my paranoia. :D

Comment: +1 for paranoia :D The clue about *tearing "it" apart* is something I actually thought about. As you figured out there is something to do with this letter "T" before building the final word.

Comment: @bobbee WORD? Oh boy. This riddle is like ogres.

Comment: It is not that hard. Once you have it you will punch yourself :) Yes, WORD (tags are useful sometimes :P).

Comment: @bobbee Ok, final edit. I'm gonna go grab a soda from the store while I await my imminent self-punch. Lol

Comment: Prepare yourself :D

Answer (score 0):

Building on the existing answers...

Clutching at straws perhaps, but I think the final answer is:

> TAURUS

The good disguise wins
so you act as twins:

> could be V instead of U

What fits in between
has been found before
But one was different,
and is waiting for more:

> Instead of S & U in the top line you have S & V. It's different, you need T and U in between instead of just one letter. One extra letter, A?, and you have the letters of TAURUS

It's not only a symbol
but like a small lagoon
Rising from the dead
every afternoon

> Taurus is a star sign, it's rising in the early afternoon where I am at the moment. I've seen it the last few nights, looking out for Comet Lovejoy!

Comment: I hope you have more luck with finding the comet! ;)

Comment: Sadly I did not! :)